# Surface Area of sphere in between two cone

Tags: calculus

So I have the circle $1 = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ and the cones $z = \,\sqrt{\,{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,}\,$ and $z = -\,\sqrt{\,{x^{2} + y^{2}}\,}\,$.

I'm trying to find the surface integral between the two cones of the sphere but not sure if I'm approaching it right. I know how to parameterize and solve the integral of a cone and sphere.

Do you just parameterize the sphere with $\pi/4 \geq \Phi \geq 5\pi/4$ and that's it $?$.

or do you also have to subtract the surface integral of the two cones $?$.

Comment: If it’s really “surface area of the cone between (whatever)” then you would just integrate on the sphere. Why would you consider the cone area at all? Also, where did $5\pi/4$ come from?

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize the sphere:
$$r(\theta,\phi) = \left[\begin{matrix}\sin{\left(\theta \right)} \cos{\left(\phi \right)}\\\sin{\left(\phi \right)} \sin{\left(\theta \right)}\\\cos{\left(\theta \right)}\end{matrix}\right]\; (0\leq \theta \leq \pi) \land(0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi)$$
Then solve for the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$ that make the cone intersect the circle i.e $x^2 + y^2 = \dfrac{1}{2}$ $\implies \sin\phi = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$. Now just do the regular surface integral with the constrained limits:
$$\iint_S \,d\textbf{S} = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \int_0^{2\pi} \left|r_u \times r_\theta \right| \,d\theta d\phi \\ 
= \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \int_0^{2\pi} \left|\sin \theta\right| \,d\theta d\phi = 2\pi$$